# Outlook Refresh Interval for iCal subscriptions (webcal://)

Tags: outlook, icalendar, webcal

When Outlook 2007 and 2010 subscribe to an internet calendar (via a `webcal://` link to an iCalendar or vCalendar file), how often do they auto-update?  Is there a way to configure this, either in the file downloaded or in Outlook preferences?  I know the file can specify a minimum refresh interval (via the `X-PUBLISHED-TTL` field), but I don't see a way to explicitly specify a recommended interval.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Outlook relies on the custom property X-PUBLISHED-TTL to set the download frequency but unless set in the file you subscribe to, there is no way to force within outlook an update frequency (nor in google calendar).

Comment: Please explain this phrase "... but unless set in the file you subscribe to ...". `X-PUBLISHED-TTL` can only be in file?

Comment: @AlexG what it means is that unless the calendar file you subscribed to ha s this custom property set, there is no way to force outlook to refresh faster.

Answer (score 14):

For Outlook 2013 if you hit send/receive that will sync the calendars as well.
To adjust that interval go to File > Options > Advanced then scroll down to find Send/Receive. The options to adjust the intervals for auto Send/Receive are found there.

Answer (score 5):

With many calendars being integrated into the Cloud, these settings (X-PUBLISHED-TTL and REFRESH-INTERVAL) **no longer work** on Google Calendar and many newer versions of Outlook. I've tested this myself.

If you think about it, Google and Outlook likely and intentionally ignore any specified refresh rate to prevent DNS attacks. Basically, with millions of integrated calendars in their systems, some people could set a refresh rate every second and if they obey these settings, it could crash their servers. So, it's likely that they refresh whenever they feel like it.

Comment: I guess you mean Denial-of-Service (DoS) attack?

Answer (score 4):

I have Outlook 2017. Under "Send/Receive" you can select "Send/Receive Groups" and then define a new group for the internet calendar with a unique sync time.

Answer (score 1):

(My answer from Mar 2014 doesn't work anymore.)

To trick Outlook into refreshing an Internet Calendar, go to

File:: Account Settings:: Account Settings (button):: Internet Calendars (tab)

Then choose the calendar you wish to refresh, click "Change...", stick a space in the description (or remove a space), then click OK.

Your calendar should now be refreshed.

Comment: What really? A nightmare